# (SOLVED) Unresolved reference: enableEdgeToEdge in onCreate function JetPack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm following Android Basic Course and the solution code provided has `enableEdgeToEdge()` function call in `onCreate()` in MainActivity. When I use this line of code, I get `Unresolved reference: enableEdgeToEdge` error.

Couldn't find a solution to it despite trying multiple imports and looking on the Internet for the issue. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Code available on GitHub: https://github.com/alghe-global/Kotlin/blob/4a25e707d4efc3edf09c7f637635adec8f6e876b/AndroidBasicsCourse/TipTime/app/src/main/java/com/example/tiptime/MainActivity.kt#L36

N.B. Solution code from Google is available @ https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-tip-calculator/blob/29dddab0d5d911f1607bc5602249f89012f4d45e/app/src/main/java/com/example/tiptime/MainActivity.kt#L54

Trying to `import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge` and call `enableEdgeToEdge()` in `onCreate(...)` gives the error `Unresolved reference: enableEdgeToEdge` on both the import `enableEdgeToEdge` and the function call `enableEdgeToEdge()`

---

adding `implementation("androidx.activity:activity:1.8.1")` to `build.gradle.kts` (Module :app) allowed me to use `enableEdgeToEdge`

Comment: you need to update to latest version of ```androidx.activity:activity:1.8.1``` to use ```enableEdgeToEdge``` features.

Comment: thanks, @ChiragThummar - adding `implementation("androidx.activity:activity:1.8.1")` to `build.gradle.kts` (Module :app) allowed me to use `enableEdgeToEdge`

Comment: would you please upvote my comment. it motivates me. :)

Comment: I'm unable. Can you add your comment as an answer to the post so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 11):

**Jetpack Compose** Team Has Introduced The `enableEdgeToEdge()` to avoid Boilerplate code related to System Bars Like Status Bar, Navigation Bar, etc

you need to update to the latest version of `implemenration('androidx.activity:activity:1.8.1')` to use `enableEdgeToEdge` features.